# How to display in View List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In View "Index" output list of users, their names, messages date, messages. And near with every have link "Info".
How to display in View "Info" `List<string> ListMessage` of user after click on link "Info"?
Output only  is empty table :(

ASP.NET is a hardcore.

This is my **Model**:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

My **Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(User user)
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users;
        if (user.Name == users.Where(i => i.Name == user.Name).ToString())
        {
            user.ListMessage = new List<string>();
            user.ListMessage.Add(user.Message);          
        }
        user.ListMessage = new List<string>();
        user.ListMessage.Add(user.Message);
        ViewBag.Customers = users;
        user.Date = DateTime.Now;
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();            
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Info(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users;
        ViewBag.Customers = users;
        var c = new User();
        c.ListMessage = new List<string>();
        ViewBag.Messages = c.ListMessage;
        return View(c.ListMessage);
    }
```

And **View "Info":**

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "All messages";
}
@using MessageBank.Models
@model List<string>
        <table>               
            <tr>
                <td><p>Id</p></td>
                <td><p>Name</p></td>
                <td><p>Time</p></td>
                <td><p>Message</p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var el in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td><p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => el)</p></td>
                <td><p>@el</p></td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

Comment: What is `MessageBank.Models`?  You want your view to accept user, then simply do @foreach(var item in model) { }.  Also why are you passing a dynamic when your dumping th dynamic as a view model.

Comment: @Greg, this directive is unnecessary.

Comment: What directive is unnecessary?  You dumping customer data into a `ViewBag` is unnecessary.  You passing a property into a `ViewBag` is unnecessary.  You pass a model to the view, then iterate.  Your table is empty, because you have the list, then do `= new List` making it empty, then never repopulate.

Comment: Are you populating `c.ListMessage` anywhere?  I can just see `c.ListMessage = new List<string>();`.  If you actually populate with some values does it work? Try `c.ListMessage = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };`

Comment: @haldo I am added in Controller method "Index". In "Index" i am add messages. See please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to get the user matching an `id`.  You also need to populate `user.ListMessage` You could try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Info(int id)
{
    // get user with user.Id == id
    User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        // handle null
    }

    // populate listmessage
    user.ListMessage = new List<string> { user.Message };

    // send a List<string> to view
    return View(user.ListMessage);
}
```

Then the table should be populated in the view using the `foreach` loop.

---

If you prefer, you could return a `user` to the `Info` view.  In that case you can change to:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Info(int id)
{
    User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);    

    // populate ListMessage
    user.ListMessage = new List<string> { user.Message };

    // return User model to view    
    return View(user);
}
```

Then in the view update the `foreach` to something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "All messages";
}

@model YourNamespace.Models.User

    <table>   
        <tr>
            <th>Message</th>     
        <tr>           

        @foreach (var el in Model.ListMessage)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => el)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

   // you can access Model.Id, Model.Name, Model.Date, Model.Message in this view too
```

Comment: thanks you so mutch!
In Model.ListMessages - NullReferenceException :( 
should will I set memory for list? Where ?

Comment: After you save changes, are the values in `ListMessage` saved to the database?  You could try include: `User user = db.Users.Include(u => u.ListMessage).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);` when you get the user from the database @G3k0S

Answer (score 1):

You did not init values for ListMessage.
I tried to init `c.ListMessage = new List<string> { "Test1", "Test2" };`

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Info(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users;
        ViewBag.Customers = users;
        var c = new User();
        c.ListMessage = new List<string> { "Test1", "Test2" };
        ViewBag.Messages = c.ListMessage;
        return View(c.ListMessage);
    }
```

It show Test1 and Test2 value in the table.

Also not sure why you assign 2 ViewBags without using them?

May be you want `c.ListMessage = db.Users.Select(c=>c.Message).ToList()` ?

Answer (score 0):

TY all for help!

@haldo Why did you deleted your message? You helped me! Thx!

**Model:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Info(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
        user.ListMessage = new List<string>() { user.Message };
        return View(user.ListMessage);
    }
```

**View:**

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "All messages";
}
@using MessageBank.Models
@model IEnumerable<string>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Info</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Info</h3>
        <table>        
            <tr>
                <td><p>Message</p></td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var el in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => el)</p></td>
                    @*<td><p>@el</p></td>*@
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        @foreach (var el in Model)
        {
            <ul>
                <li><p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => el)</p></li>
                @*<td><p>@el</p></td>*@
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```